# Eliminar registros de datos en base a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, tengo la duda si se puede realizar lo siguiente que tengo pensado.

Tengo una tabla que muestra artículos con su ultimo costo de compra y fecha de compra pero como se compra con diferentes proveedores me muestra varias veces el articulo pero con diferentes fechas de compra y precios, quisiera que solo me mostrara la ultima fecha de compra y no todas como pudiera hacerle tengo el siguiente código.

```
select C.NOMBRE, A.PRECIO_UCOM , B.fecha_precio_ult_compra
FROM
PRECIOS_COMPRA_DET A
LEFT JOIN
PRECIOS_COMPRA B
ON
B.PRECIO_COMPRA_ID = A.precio_compra_id
LEFT JOIN
ARTICULOS C
ON
C.ARTICULO_ID = B.ARTICULO_ID
GROUP BY
C.NOMBRE,A.PRECIO_UCOM,B.FECHA_PRECIO_ULT_COMPRA
```

Y me muestra una tabla parecida a esta:

| NOMBRE | PRECIO_UCOM | FECHA_PRECIO_ULT_COMPRA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DETERGENTE LIQUIDO | 306.89 | 13.09.2013 |
| DETERGENTE LIQUIDO | 300.21 | 25.10.2015 |
| DETERGENTE LIQUIDO | 232.32 | 10.01.2021 |
| DETERGENTE POLVO | 350.21 | 25.10.2015 |
| DETERGENTE POLVO | 256.32 | 10.01.2021 |

Y quisiera que solo mostrara el siguiente registro:

| NOMBRE | PRECIO_UCOM | FECHA_PRECIO_ULT_COMPRA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DETERGENTE LIQUIDO | 232.32 | 10.01.2021 |
| DETERGENTE POLVO | 256.32 | 10.01.2021 |

Por su atención gracias, disculpe si se ve feo el acomodo o algo parecido apenas estoy aprendiendo a usar esta comunidad.

Comment: Puedes ordenar la consulta de manera descendente por la fecha de compra.

Comment: Pero en ese caso me seguiría mostrando todos los registros no?, y solamente quiero que me muestre los de la fecha mas resiente.

Comment: Limitalos al primero y listo... LIMIT = 1

Comment: Pero supongamos que tengo un resultado de unos 30 mil registros con diferentes artículos entre 6 a 8 mil artículos diferentes, pero con diferentes fechas de compra, al aplicar lo del limit solo traería la ultima compra realizada en el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente, nos dices como te fue.

```
SELECT TOP(1) C.NOMBRE, A.PRECIO_UCOM , B.fecha_precio_ult_compra
FROM
PRECIOS_COMPRA_DET A
LEFT JOIN
PRECIOS_COMPRA B
ON
B.PRECIO_COMPRA_ID = A.precio_compra_id
LEFT JOIN
ARTICULOS C
ON
C.ARTICULO_ID = B.ARTICULO_ID
GROUP BY
C.NOMBRE,A.PRECIO_UCOM,B.FECHA_PRECIO_ULT_COMPRA
ORDER BY B.FECHA_PRECIO_ULT_COMPRA DESC
```

Comment: Explica de mejor manera tu respuesta para que sea considerada como una. Sino, aplícala como comentario mejor.

Comment: Ya lo hice como me comento pero es parecido a la respuesta de excorpion, me traería la ultima compra realizada, pero lo que quiero es que me traiga la ultima compra de cada articulo, hay artículos que tienen 20 compras, hay otros con 10 y asi sucesivamente, solo quiero traerme la ultima de cada articulo.

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Procura que tu respuesta tenga siempre una breve explicación de qué hace el código sugerido, cómo se usa y qué hace diferente al código del OP

Comment: Quizá en vez de poner la consulta que no te funciona, podrías poner un script de creación y llenado de datos (solo algunas filas que contengan datos que sirvan) de `PRECIOS_COMPRA`, `PRECIOS_COMPRA_DET` y `ARTICULOS`, para obtener una respuesta que se adapte a lo que solicitas.